# Display edited columns only using Audit Triggers in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, audit-logging

I am using Microsoft SSMS.

I am trying to create an audit Trigger for my `TestTable` so that when a user edits or inserts any data, it will be recorded in this `ChangeLogTable`. The query below works and I am able to record any changes to the table.

However, whenever a user edits a row, it will record everything including the columns that are not edited. For example, if a user edits the `TestDateTime`, the `TestStatus` will appear in the `ChangeLogTable` even though there were no changes to it.

How do I change the query so that only the edited columns are recorded?

```
Create trigger test_Audit
on TestTable
after Insert, update
not for replication
as

Declare @operation char(10)

if exists(select * from deleted)
set @operation = 'Edit'
else
set @operation = 'Insert'


if UPDATE (TestDateTime)
insert ChangeLog
(TableName, ModifiedBy, ChangeLogDateTime, AuditAction, WorkScheduleID, ChangedColumn , OldValue, NewValue)
select
'TestTable', SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), @operation, inserted.TestID,
'TestDateTime', Deleted.TestDateTime, Inserted.TestDateTime
from inserted
left outer join deleted
on inserted.TestID = deleted.TestID
and inserted.TestDateTime <> deleted.TestDateTime 


if UPDATE (TestStatus)
insert ChangeLog
(TableName, ModifiedBy, ChangeLogDateTime, AuditAction, WorkScheduleID, ChangedColumn, OldValue, NewValue)
select
'TestTable', SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), @operation, inserted.TestID,
'TestStatus', Deleted.TestStatus, Inserted.TestStatus
from inserted
left outer join deleted
on inserted.TestID = deleted.TestID
and inserted.TestStatus<> deleted.TestStatus


if UPDATE (StaffID)
insert AuditLog
(TableName, ModifiedBy, AuditDateTime, AuditAction, ID, ChangedColumn, OldValue, NewValue)
select
'TestTable', SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), @operation, inserted.TestID,
'StaffID', OSN.StaffName, NSN.StaffName
from inserted
left outer join deleted
on inserted.TestID= deleted.TestID
and inserted.StaffID <> deleted.StaffID
-- Fetch Staff Name
left outer join dbo.Staff OSN
on deleted.StaffID = OSN.StaffID
join dbo.Staff NSN
on inserted.StaffID = NSN.StaffID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have confused your join `on` clause with your `where` clause. Because you had for example `inserted.TestStatus<> deleted.TestStatus` as part of your `on` clause, you never matched a `Deleted` row if the data changed. Whereas what you wanted was to match the row on ID and then check whether the value had changed.

Note I've re-written the trigger using general best practices for clarity e.g.

1. Using table aliases
2. Making it *set-based* rather than *procedural*.
3. Handling `null` values, because you can't use the `<>` operator when either side is `null`.
4. Being consistent with what case (lower/upper/mixed) is used.
5. Using semi-colons to terminate statements.
6. Schema qualify your objects - I have assumed `dbo`.
7. Forcing a convert to `varchar` for the `datetime` column as its better to convert explicitly rather than implicitly.

```
alter trigger dbo.test_Audit
on dbo.TestTable
after insert, update
not for replication
as
begin
  set nocount on;

  declare @operation char(10) = case when exists (select * from deleted) then 'Edit' else 'Insert' end;

  insert ChangeLog (TableName, ModifiedBy, ChangeLogDateTime, AuditAction, WorkScheduleID, ChangedColumn , OldValue, NewValue)
    select
      'TestTable', suser_sname(), getdate(), @operation, I.TestID,
      'TestDateTime', convert(varchar(21),D.TestDateTime), convert(varchar(21),I.TestDateTime)
    from inserted I
    left outer join deleted D on I.TestID = D.TestID
    where coalesce(I.TestDateTime,'1 jan 1900') <> coalesce(D.TestDateTime,'1 jan 1900')
    and update(TestDateTime)
    union all
    select
    'TestTable', suser_sname(), getdate(), @operation, I.TestID,
    'TestStatus', D.TestStatus, I.TestStatus
    from inserted I
    left outer join deleted D on I.TestID = D.TestID
    where coalesce(I.TestStatus,'') <> coalesce(D.TestStatus,'')
    and update(TestStatus)
end;
```

Comment: Hi, what does "where coalesce(I.TestDateTime,'1 jan 1900') <> coalesce(D.TestDateTime,'1 jan 1900')" do?

Comment: @addsw If TestDateTime is null it uses a very old date which should never happen on purpose in your system. Its one way to handle null values.

Comment: Oh. So for other attributes other than datetime, it would look like this (I.TestStatus,' ')?

Comment: Its totally dependent on the datatype, for a string you might use a blank string, unless you need to be able to tell the different between a blank string and null. For an int you might use -1, again depending whether thats a valid value or not.

Comment: Hi, if I have a foreign key, how should the code look like so that it would also display the foreign key details (eg. StaffName from StaffID)? I will update the codes in my question.

Comment: @addsw please ask a new question... it doesn't work to continue updating a question which already has an answer.

Comment: Sorry, the link to the question is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63425300/audit-trigger-for-foreign-key