# Audit trigger for foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, audit

The code below is an Audit trigger for my `Branch` Table. It is able to record any edit or insert changes from the `Branch` table.

However, I have a foreign key `BranchZoneID` to the `BranchZone` table. I want to make it so that any changes to this foreign key will be recorded, and that it will display the `BranchZoneName` from the `BranchZone` table instead of the `BranchZoneID`.

I tried playing around with the code to create a trigger for the foreign key attribute `BranchZoneID`. However, I am unable to create a working trigger for it.

The trigger for the `BranchZoneID` is not working. What do I need to change?

```
create trigger Branch_Audit
on dbo.Branch
after insert, update
not for replication
as
begin
  set nocount on;

  declare @operation char(10) = case when exists (select * from deleted) then 'Edit' else 'Insert' end;

  insert AuditLog
(TableName, ModifiedBy, AuditDateTime, AuditAction, ID, ChangedColumn, OldValue, NewValue)
    select
      'Branch', suser_sname(), getdate(), @operation, I.BranchZoneID,
      'BranchName', convert(varchar(21),D.BranchName), convert(varchar(21),I.BranchName)
    from inserted I
    left outer join deleted D on I.BranchID = D.BranchID
    where coalesce(I.BranchName,'') <> coalesce(D.BranchName,'')
    and update(BranchName)
    union all

    select
    'Branch', suser_sname(), getdate(), @operation, I.BranchID,
    'BranchAddress', D.BranchAddress, I.BranchAddress
    from inserted I
    left outer join deleted D on I.BranchID = D.BranchID
    where coalesce(I.BranchAddress,'') <> coalesce(D.BranchAddress,'')
    and update(BranchAddress)
    union all


    select
    'Branch', suser_sname(), getdate(), @operation, I.BranchID,
    'BranchGeoLocationLat', D.BranchGeoLocationLat, I.BranchGeoLocationLat
    from inserted I
    left outer join deleted D on I.BranchID = D.BranchID
    where coalesce(I.BranchGeoLocationLat,'') <> coalesce(D.BranchGeoLocationLat,'')
    and update(BranchGeoLocationLat)
    union all


    select
    'Branch', suser_sname(), getdate(), @operation, I.BranchID,
    'BranchGeoLocationLong', D.BranchGeoLocationLong, I.BranchGeoLocationLong
    from inserted I
    left outer join deleted D on I.BranchID = D.BranchID
    where coalesce(I.BranchGeoLocationLong,'') <> coalesce(D.BranchGeoLocationLong,'')
    and update(BranchGeoLocationLong)
    union all

    select
    'Branch', SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), @operation, I.BranchID,
    'BranchZoneID', OWD.BranchZoneName, NWD.BranchZoneName
    from inserted I
    left outer join deleted D on I.BranchID = D.BranchID
    where coalesce(I.BranchZoneID,'') <> coalesce(D.BranchZoneID,'')
    and update(BranchZoneID)
    -- Fetch Branch Zone Name
    on deleted.BranchZoneID = OWD.BranchZoneID
    join dbo.BranchZone NWD
    on inserted.BranchZoneID = NWD.BranchZoneID

end;
```

Comment: So what's the big deal? You join to the appropriate table. What you can't do is simply "invent" an alias and refer to it in your select statement. And for future reference, when your problem includes errors you should post the complete and actual error messages. And you should actually mention that your code generates errors - which this does since OWD and NWD are aliases that have not been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just got confused with your join... join correctly and it works as intended. And remember when using a table alias you can only reference the table using the alias from then on e.g. `I` instead of `Inserted`.

Also assuming `BranchZoneID` is an `int` you need to `coalesce` it to an unused `int` e.g. `0` not an empty string.

```
select
    'Branch', suser_sname(), getdate(), @operation, I.BranchID
    , 'BranchZoneID', OWD.BranchZoneName, NWD.BranchZoneName
from inserted I
left outer join deleted D on I.BranchID = D.BranchID

-- Fetch Branch Zone Names
left join dbo.BranchZone OWD on OWD.BranchZoneID = D.BranchZoneID
left join dbo.BranchZone NWD on NWD.BranchZoneID = I.BranchZoneID

where coalesce(I.BranchZoneID,0) <> coalesce(D.BranchZoneID,0)
and update(BranchZoneID);
```

And if `BranchZoneID` is a `uniqueidentifer` you would use:

```
where coalesce(I.BranchZoneID,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') <> coalesce(D.BranchZoneID,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```

When using `coalesce` to compare values in this way, you need to choose a value which is valid for the datatype but which is invalid in your data.

Comment: Hi, if the BranchZoneID is an uniqueidentifier, what do I have to change the '0' in  (I.BranchZoneID,0) to?

Comment: When I try to edit the BranchZoneID in my website, this error pops up: "SqlException: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

Comment: The Data type of 'OldValue' and 'NewValue' is Nvarchar(250). However, I doubt that I need to change its data type.

Comment: I can't see how that would happen if `BranchZoneID` is a uniqueidentifier. Somewhere you have an `int` column which you aren't converting correctly - but without seeing your table definitions and sample data I can't offer any suggestions.

Comment: I do not have an int column in my table.

Comment: AuditLogID - uniqueidentifier, TableName -varchar (100), ModifiedBy - varchar(100), AuditDateTime - varchar(100), ID - uniqueidentifier, AuditAction - varchar(100), ChangeColumn - varchar(100), OldValue - varchar(100), NewValue - varchar(100)